# Sobolev space exercise

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I need to show $|f|_{L^\infty}\leq c|f|_{H^2} = c(\int_{\mathbb R^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^2|\hat f(\xi)|^2 d\xi )^{1/2}$, assume $f\in H^2(\mathbb R^2)$

I think I can trasnfer $f\ = \int \hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi\cdot x}d\xi$,  and $|f(x)|=\int|\hat f(\xi)|d\xi$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz to get the $H^2$ norm. But I encounter a troubles:

1. the infinity norm is the esssup $|f|$, but this representation kind of far away from this inequality.  Is there any other way to represent the infinity norm?

Comment: I don't think this is true for arbitrary $n$.  For instance, consider a function that behaves like $1/|x|$ near $x=0$.  For large enough $n$, you can ensure that this function and several of its derivatives are all in $L^2$, but it isn't bounded.

Comment: fixed, is that correct?

Comment: Isn't that $|f|_{H^s}^s = \int (1+|\xi|^2)^s|\hat f(\xi)|^2d\xi$

Comment: Sorry, yes, it looks correct now.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, dimension =2, i did not notice this line

Comment: I think this is the most direct proof. Since functions in $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ are automatically continuous, the essential supremum is equal to the supremum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in the page 272, Proposition 1.5 from this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=0xtSyLjsphkC&pg=PA270&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)

In the demonstration, the author shows that $H^{1+\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is continuously immersed in $C^\alpha(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for $\alpha\in (0,1)$. On the other hand, $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is continuously immersed in $H^{1+\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $C^\alpha(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is continuously immersed in $C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, hence you can conclude.

Comment: Sorry, what is the relation here with $L^\infty$?

Comment: In this case $|f|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}|f(x)|$

Comment: But $|f(x)|$ can go to infinity on a measure 0, while the infinity norm is finite.

Comment: @TianyiXia, Im using a abusive notation but here $C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ mean  the space of functions $f$ such that $\|f\|_\alpha<\infty$ and $\|f\|_0<\infty$ respectivley,  where $\|f\|_\alpha<\infty$ is the Holder norm and $\|f\|_0<\infty$ is the sup norm.